# Is there a way to use Branch deeplinks while the app is already running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, branch.io

As Branch documentation states and my current implementation goes, the branch links are detected in the AppDelegate, a view controller is registered accordingly and then launched from there.

Is there a way I can do this not in the AppDelegate but elsewhere?
My main issue is that if my app is already launched and someone clicks on a Branch Deeplink, it works as it should but takes me back to the launch screen of the app, rather than staying at the currently launched view.

I tried using

```
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:NO];
```

and launching the view controller from elsewhere, but now I don't understand how the "deepLinkingCompletionDelegate" will be called to fetch the data accompanying the link.

Comment: docs point that you can register your specific VC for deeplinking https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/#configure-view-controller-to-accept-deep-links

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch here:

These code snippets don't *need* to be in your AppDelegate, but they do need to be called in the correct app lifecycle methods. The typical place for these to be defined is the AppDelegate, and it would be a much more advanced implementation to put them anywhere else. Even if you did, the effect would be the same and you wouldn't avoid the issue you've identified.

It sounds like you are using our basic [automatic deep link routing](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/ios/) approach. What you want to do is [build your own custom router](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method), so that you can decide intelligently what to do with the link data. In other words, you'll still *receive* the link params right away, but you'll be able to decide to *not open the launch screen* if the app is already running.

Comment: Hi Alex. We try to get the parameters using custom router approach and we can't get any parameters to check the navigation after.  Do u know what can be wrong? The links work but on debug mode I can't get any parameters with the code provided on build your own custom router.

Comment: @Andreas777 this could be caused by a number of things. A common one is if the Branch key used in your app doesn't match the one used to create the link. I'd check that first, and then if it's still not working go ahead and ask a new question with more details or even [submit a ticket to our Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)